# High refresh rate not detected on laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver, nvidia-settings

I have a razer blade 15 with RTX 3070 Ti. I installed the appropriate Nvidia driver but I don't have the 240Hz option as I do on windows.

Did anyone face the same issue?

[image] [image]